# T-sql and json and XML

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, ssms

Does anybody know how to get intellisense working in query windows in SSMS for JSON methods?

I'm just getting started with querying from remote databases and for some reason when I attempt to type in methods, e.g., isjson() in the t-sql editor, not showing any of the functions.

Do I need to import any packages?

Comment: Using json in sql server is only from sql server 2016.

Comment: Thank you. XML would be the way to go I take it? Best, Michael

Comment: If remote database can return XML - it would be the best, TSQL has plenty of methods to work with XML. But if you're getting back JSON only you can use JSON-to-XML conversion functions like this one https://sqlsunday.com/2013/05/12/converting-json-data-to-xml-using-a-t-sql-function/ and still work with XML at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Really appreciate it. This is extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json Format by create this procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_query_json]
            @query nvarchar(4000) 
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

         Declare @query_adjust nvarchar(max)
         set @query_adjust = 'select ' + '''[''' 
                               + ' + replace(replace(replace(replace(replace((' 
                               + @query + '  for xml raw ),'
                               + '''<row ''' + ',' + '''{"''' + '),' 
                               + '''/>''' + ',' + '''},''' + '),' 
                               + '''" ''' + ',' + '''","''' + '),' 
                               + '''="''' + ',' + '''":"''' + ') + ' 
                               + ''']''' + ',' 
                               + ''',]''' + ',' + ''']''' + ')'


     EXECUTE sp_executesql @query_adjust 
END
```

You can test query like that :

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_query_json] 'select id,name from table'
```

this call real Table or View and change it to XML by using

```
For XML RAW
```

And replace XML tags to JSON like